# Multiplication Python Script giving wrong output

Tags: python-3.x

The Code below gives an answer for almost any number I have tested with, even a 64 digits *64 digits. But when tried with

a = 123456
b = 123456

The final answer is negative.

Up until 
a = 12345
b = 12345

The answer is correct.

Not sure where this is going wrong. I am relatively new to python so is there something I am missing out?

```
import numpy as np
a = int(input("Enter Number 1: "))
b = int(input("Enter Number 2: "))
c = 1
pos_nums = []

while b != 0:
    z = b % 10
    pos_nums.append(z *c)
    b = b // 10
    c = c*10

pos_num = np.array([pos_nums])
multiply = pos_num *a


add = np.sum(multiply)
print(add)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why numpy is playing up, but something like this appears to work, and does the same thing.

All I've done is removed the conversion to a numpy array.  Now when you multiply `pos_num` it essentially makes `a` copies of it into one list.  `sum` counts the total value of the list, which has `a` amounts of `b` stored in it.

Hope this works for you :)

```
a = int(input("Enter Number 1: "))
b = int(input("Enter Number 2: "))
c = 1
pos_nums = []

while b != 0:
    z = b % 10
    pos_nums.append(z *c)
    b = b // 10
    c = c*10

#pos_num = np.array(pos_nums)
pos_num = pos_nums

multiply = pos_num *a


add = sum(multiply)
print(add)
```

Output:

```
Enter Number 1: 123456
Enter Number 2: 123456
15241383936
```

Answer (score 0):

### numpy can't guess your next move!

you see when you define a numpy array it will assume a type for the array (like np.int16) and its not will not change unless you multiply it into something with other formats

**what happend here?**

you have multiplied a dtype=np.int32 array into an int in line:

```
multiply = pos_num *a
```

the result will be another np.int32 array (you can see that with `print(multiply.dtype)`)

numpy can not guess that you intend to extend the array into for example np.float64
(not like regular python code, because there is a great performace hit to that)

**what to do?**

just simply define the type for it! (it a good practice to do this in other codes)

```
pos_num = np.array(pos_nums, dtype=np.float64)
```